# How to offload CSS and JS files from wp-content/themes folder?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

Am using the WP Offload S3 plugin and not able to offload the CSS and JS files within the themes folder.
Am trying to use wp_enqueue_style() like below in *wp-content/themes/spark/functions.php*

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'validationEngine.jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/validationEngine.jquery.css', array(), false, 'screen' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css', array(), false, 'screen' );
```

Am not able to offload the files.
Please let me know what am I missing here.

Regards, AG

Comment: Did you actually use `wp_dequeue_style()` ( [*see codex*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) ) before you enqueued the styles again, or are these own created `css` files? Btw please use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) for a child theme.

Comment: @Charles: So I tried the child theme way. By reading the documentation I got to know that we have to edit any theme files then edit them in child theme. Assuming this is correct?

I followed this https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes and created the functions.php

So if we have to enqueue any files, should that be done in child themes functions.php instead of the parent functions.php?

Comment: Yes, every change you wish to make you will do in the child theme folder. Now add all your own functions in the child theme `functions.php`. Wish to change some in a parent template file? **Copy** that file into child theme folder and make there your changes. This way you can be sure that when updated(*by author*) your changes still remain save in the child theme files. *Note* read always change log files(*of the parent theme*) before you update a parent theme, to be sure it won't interfere with your own function(s) in the child theme.

Comment: @Charles: I did make all the changes but when I preview the site with the child theme the pages looks odd without any CSS. Basically it's not find all the CSS files.
In my child theme folder I just have 2 files... style.css which is kind of empty and the other is functions.php which has small function.

Comment: On [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) : do a search for *If it is not, you will need to enqueue it as well.* the function you see directly after that you have to add to your `functions.php` (*in the child theme folder*). This will take care for loading the parent `style.css` and your changes made in your child theme `style.css` (*if made any*). But thats all I can say(*This is kinda off-topic when it is about your question*) about how to use child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a child theme?

Is get_template_directory_uri() function returning the correct URL?

My suggestion is to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'validationEngine.jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/validationEngine.jquery.css', array(), false, 'screen' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css', array(), false, 'screen' );
```

Comment: I don't know what a child theme is but this the file that am editing - wp-content/themes/spark/functions.php
I tried using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead before but no luck.
Also how do I check if get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is returning the correct URL?

Comment: Do you see the js In the view source of the page?

Do you have the required addon in your site?

[https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/doc/assets-addon/](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/doc/assets-addon/)

Comment: @Maga, please read [following.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) *Everything* you add/edit in a parent theme *(as it seems you are doing)* will be gone after the next theme update. Create first a child theme and make all your changes in the specific files you want *(or create own plugins)* so they are "save" and not changed after a theme update.

Comment: @Pabamato: Yes I do see those 2 CSS files in the view source but their URL is not S3, its getting served from EC2.
Which JS file are you referring to?
Yes, we have a Licensed version of the Asset addon installed via WordPress plugin page. However we are having proxy issues while activating the License but that's a different issue. Am assuming that is not causing any issue to wp_enqueue_style().

Comment: @Charles: Sure, ill try the child theme way. Are you saying that its a best practice while am editing any theme files OR you are saying this will resolve my issue??

Comment: @Maga, it is the best and for 85% of ppl the only way to be sure that all made changes will be okay/save. A child theme will override parent settings. *(if done correctly)*